# Multiple pushbutton read simulatenously

Tags: switches

I have 20 pushbutton inputs where any number of inputs can be pressed simultaneously. I have to read the output of the buttons and transmit it. I am planning to use a binary to decimal encoder for reading all the 20 inputs at a time and convert them to decimal for serial output to the wireless device for transmission. Is this a better approach than having a microcontroller? Also can matrix of 5 X 4 switches be a better choice for reducing the number of input pins? My objective is to make the design as smaller as compact as possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the 74C923 yet?

Comment: Define "simultaneously".  Do you need a true simultaneous measurement? Or is polling at a few kHz enough? If so, you can easily use a matrix arrangement.

Comment: Simultaneously - Any number of switches can be pressed and what I am interested is which switches are ON and which are OFF at a single poll

Comment: Can 74C923 handle multiple input switch press at the same time? Also will the output of 74C923 (that I will be getting from pressing multiple push buttons) be able to identify which switches I have pressed in the input?

Comment: I am using pushbutton inputs for sensing the hand pressure pattern when pressed. Have 20 pushbutton switches in a square type and when we press some of the switches get pressed and others do not. I am looking to transmit this pattern wirelessly to a receiver

Comment: The 74C922 and 74C923 are discontinued parts, but Ebay and other parts brokers may have some. Or consider a 20 pin PIC MCU and just use MPLAB assembler.

Answer (score 2):

20 inputs needs 20 pins. 5 x 4 matrix requires 9 but for simultaneous button press reading you will require a diode on each button to prevent backfeeds from the column being scanned to any of the others.

[image]

*Figure 1. Problems with scanning keyboards with simultaneous multiple keypresses. In the example column C1 is being scanned and since only S1 is pressed the expected result is that row R0 only should return a 'pressed' signal via S1. If S2 and S7 are pressed as well a backfeed occurs onto C2 and R1 will also return a 'pressed signal' indicating that S6 is pressed as well.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Addition of a diode on each key prevents the backfeed problem. [Source](http://blog.damnsoft.org/a-portable-general-purpose-keyboard/).*

Since it seems that you are going to require a micro to encode the information it seems a pity to add additional hardware for the keyboard.

You may find that your decision is determined by the available keyboard type.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using pushbutton inputs for sensing the hand pressure pattern when pressed. Have 20 pushbutton switches in a square type and when we press some of the switches get pressed and others do not. I am looking to transmit this pattern wirelessly to a receiver

Comment: That's fine. Is there a question?